# Offset for consumer group resetted for one partition

Tags: apache-kafka

During the last maintenance of Kafka, which required a rolling restart of kafka brokers, we witnessed a reset for consumer group offsets for certain partitions.

At 11:14 am, everything is fine for the consumer group and we don't see a consumer lag:

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 0          105130857       105130857       0          st-...
...
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 6          78591770        78591770        0          st-...
```

However 5 minutes later, during the rolling restart of brokers, we have a reset for one partition and a consumer lag of millions of events.

```
$ bin/kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server XXX:9093,XXX...  --command-config secrets.config  --group st-xx --describe
Note: This will not show information about old Zookeeper-based consumers.

[2019-08-26 12:44:13,539] WARN Connection to node -5 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2019-08-26 12:44:13,707] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=st-xx] Connection to node -5 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
Consumer group 'st-xx' has no active members.

TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 0          105132096       105132275       179            
...
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx 6          15239401        78593165        63353764   ...
```

In the last two hours, the offset for the partition hasn't recovered and we need to patch it now manually. We had similar issues during the last rolling restart of brokers.

Has anyone seen something like this before? The only clue we could find is [this ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-5600), however we run Kafka version: [1.0.1-kafka3.1.0](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/3-1-x/topics/kafka_fi_310.html#kafka_fi_300),